# compare difference in lists in a for loop

Tags: python, list

i have a function that goes and grabs the tag structure of a few XML files. Therefore, using a for loop, I end up a variable lt that is a list of list of the tags. In one loop, I would have:

```
lt = [['MLB', 'OF', '25'], ['NBA', 'PG', '26']]
```

The next loop would be something like :

```
lt = [['MLB', 'OF', '25'], ['NBA', 'PG', 'Lakers' '26']]
```

Because of the for loop, my variable names stays static. Is there a way I can compare the lists than are coming in and say if lists are different from one another?

Comment: The equality operator should do this...

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the lists directly as usual:

```
>>> l1 = [['MLB', 'OF', '25'], ['NBA', 'PG', '26']]
>>> l1 == [['MLB', 'OF', '25'], ['NBA', 'PG', '26']]
True
>>> l1 == [['MLB', 'OF', '25'], ['NBA', 'PG', '27']]
False
```

However, if you're interested in the comparison of "internal" lists set and can't rely on their order, simply compare sorted ones:

```
>>> l1 = [['MLB', 'OF', '25'], ['NBA', 'PG', '26']]
>>> l2 = [['NBA', 'PG', '26'], ['MLB', 'OF', '25']]
>>> l1 == l2
False
>>> sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)
True
```

If you need to compare the lists coming from different iterations, append each new one to some general list from outside the loop, so previous ones would be accessible by an index of correspondent iteration. Something like:

```
results = []

for i, item in enumerate(items):
    # your logic from the loop, that gives us new_list
    results.append(new_list)
    # now we can compare it with one of the previous results
    identity = results[i] == results[i - 1] if i > 0 else False
```

Answer (score 0):

... how about just keeping it for reference

```
last = None
for ...:
    lt = ..
    if last is not None and lt != last:
        print "different line"
    last = lt
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little unclear, but I think I get what you're trying to do: you want to compare values in one loop step to a previous step?  If so capture the values in a dict with a key that references the loop somehow:

```
tags_by_file = {}
for file in file_list:
    tags = get_tags(file)
    tags_by_file[file] = tags
    ...
```

After that you can reference any previous file's tag.

Answer (score 0):

To get the elements that are the same in the lists:

```
list_1 = [['MLB', 'OF', '25'], ['NBA', 'PG', '26']]
list_2 = [['MLB', 'OF', '25'], ['NBA', 'PG', 'Lakers' '26'], []]

list_3 = []
for element in list_1:
  if (element in list_2):
    list_3.append(element)


print(list_3)
```

To also see if they are different you can compare the length of the combined list to the length of original lists. So just add

```
len(list_3) == len(list_1) and (len(list_3) == len(list_2)
```